# Calculus of variations with a change in parameter after some time.

Tags: euler-lagrange-equation, variational-analysis

$$\text{fun}:=\int_0^\infty e^{-rt}\left[u(c'(t))+w-p\,c'(t)\right]e^{-b\,c(t)}\,dt. $$

I am maximizing this objective function with some function c(t). As an extension, I want to get a solution when w changes from w1 to w2 at t=100 as well. Then, the objective function will be divided into two functions; 0~100 and 100~.

I am trying to find a continuous function (not necessarily differentiable). Then, is it enough to solve each part separately setting an initial condition of the second part equal to c*(t=100)? (Here c* is the solution for the first part).

The first that I can remind is that max{f(x)+g(x)} <= max{f(x)}+max{g(x)}. However, here, I think I am adding one more constraint for max{g(x)} compared to the LHS problem.

I was wondering if there is a reference that I can look at. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You have not put in enough detail to allow us to understand why you are asking.

Comment: Thank you. I could find a function from my previous question. I just edited!

Comment: Okay - now I can follow it. If you try to solve them separately, then you have no guarantee that $c$ will be continuous at $100$. It almost certainly will not be. If you want a continuous function, you must solve over the entire domain.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Indeed, my question was not about whether it would be continuous or not.  I was asking if two solutions coincide or not.

Comment: How would they coincide? One has definitive values on $[0,100]$, the other on $[100, \infty]$. Outside of those regions, each has no condition to define it.